# Looping over network subnet

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a Python Loop over IP subnet address, I have tried the below one and it worked fine:

```
import ipaddress

for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network(u'192.168.1.0/24'):
    print(ip)
```

Now I want to Pass the subnet address `192.168.1.0/24` as arguments instead of using a fixed value.

Comment: Learn about creating a function in python. See https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function.

Comment: do you mean you want to specify the subnet address as part of your command line invocation?  like:  python mycode.py 192.168.1.0/24

Comment: Yes exactly..  i tried the code in the comments with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Your first python function - a basic example

```
def greet(name):
    """
    This function greets to
    the person passed in as
    a parameter
    """
    print("Hello, " + name + ". Good morning!")
```

And the function that you need to have

```
import ipaddress
import sys

def subnet_printer(subnet)
    for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network(subnet):
        print(ip)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #TODO verify the argument was passed
    subnet_printer(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Thnaks a lot @Baldetman, i want to pass the Subnet from the Command line when running the script, Something like [root@]# ./IPLoop.py 192.168.1.0/24    (Details of the the script in the above comments)

Comment: @moisla code was modified. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @moisla and welcome to StackOverflow.

If you wish to pass the ip range as a parameter from the command-line, here is a great explanation on how to achieve this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

The Python `sys` module provides access to any command-line arguments via `sys.argv`. `sys.argv[0]` is the program ie. script name so if you want to get the first parameter it would be `sys.argv[1]`

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print(str(sys.argv[1]))
```

So running the test.py like this:

```
python test.py some_arg
```

Would print:

```
some_arg
```

Comment: I have tried the below script but got some errors:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import ipaddress

print "start"

Subnet=sys.argv[1]
print (Subnet)
for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network(Subnet):
    print(ip)


print "end"

Comment: [root@]# ./IPLoop.py 192.168.1.0/24
start
192.168.1.0/24
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./IPLoop.py", line 11, in <module>
    for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network(Subnet):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipaddress.py", line 1619, in __init__
    self.network_address = IPv4Address(address)

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipaddress.py", line 1399, in __init__
    self._check_packed_address(address, 4)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipaddress.py", line 553, in _check_packed_address
    expected_len, self._version))
ipaddress.AddressValueError: '192.168.1.0/24' (len 14 != 4) is not permitted as an IPv4 address. Did you pass in a bytes (str in Python 2) instead of a unicode object?
[root@]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i got it working.. "Unicode" was the point that i was looking for

#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import ipaddress

print "start"

Subnet=sys.argv[1]
print (Subnet)
for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network(unicode (Subnet)):
print(ip)

print "end"